# Error POO en C++: "is not a direct base of"

Tags: c++, poo

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de herencia en la universidad. Y me sale un unico error. Adjunto a continuación todos el código fuente y una foto del error en la terminal al compilar crupier.cc. La cosa es que he probado de todo y sé lo que es la herencia, pero no veo mi error por ninguna parte. He compilado el archivo persona.cc y me funciona correctamente. Por tanto deduzco que el error estará en crupier.h o crupier.cc, pero no entiendo donde está el error. Si alguno sabe el error o algo que mejorar en mi código que me lo diga.

nombre archivo:persona.h

```
#ifndef __persona__
#define __persona__
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
class Persona{
    private:
        string dni_,nombre_,apellidos_,direccion_,localidad_,provincia_,pais_;
        int edad_;
    public:
        inline string getDNI(){return dni_;}
        inline void setDNI(string dni){dni_=dni;}
        inline string getNombre(){return nombre_;}
        inline void setNombre(string nombre){nombre_=nombre;}
        inline string getApellidos(){return apellidos_;}
        inline void setApellidos(string apellidos){apellidos_=apellidos;}
        inline string getDireccion(){return direccion_;}
        inline void setDireccion(string direccion){direccion_=direccion;}
        inline string getLocalidad(){return localidad_;}
        inline void setLocalidad(string localidad){localidad_=localidad;}
        inline string getProvincia(){return provincia_;}
        inline void setProvincia(string provincia){provincia_=provincia;}
        inline string getPais(){return pais_;}
        inline void setPais(string pais){pais_=pais;}
        int getEdad();
        bool setEdad(int edad);
        Persona(string dni,string nombre="",string apellidos="",int edad=0,string direccion="",string localidad="",string provincia="",string pais="");
        inline string getApellidosyNombre(){return apellidos_+","+nombre_;}
        bool mayor();
};
#endif
```

nombre archivo:persona.cc

```
bool Persona::mayor(){
    if(edad_>=18){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

Persona::Persona(string dni,string nombre,string apellidos,int edad,string direccion,string localidad,string provincia,string pais){
    setApellidos(apellidos);
    setDNI(dni);
    setNombre(nombre);
    setEdad(edad);
    setDireccion(direccion);
    setLocalidad(localidad);
    setProvincia(provincia);
    setPais(pais);
}

bool Persona::setEdad(int edad){
    if(edad<0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        edad_=edad;
        return true;
    }
}
```

nombre archivo: crupier.h

```
#include "persona.h"

class Crupier{
    private:
        string codigo_;
    public:
       Crupier(string dni,string codigo,string nombre="",string apellidos="",int edad=0,string direccion="",string localidad="",string provincia="",string pais="");
        inline string getCodigo(){return codigo_;}
        inline void setCodigo(string codigo){codigo_=codigo;}
};
```

nombre archivo: crupier.cc

```
#include "crupier.h"

Crupier::Crupier(string dni,string codigo,string nombre,string apellidos,int edad,string direccion,string localidad,string provincia,string pais):Persona(dni,nombre,apellidos,edad,direccion,localidad,provincia,pais){
    setCodigo(codigo);
}
```

Aquí os pongo la foto del error por pantalla al compilar crupier.cc:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que defines el crupier sin decirle que herede de la clase persona.

```
#include "persona.h"

class Crupier : public Persona{
    private:
        string codigo_;
    public:
       Crupier(string dni,string codigo,string nombre="",string apellidos="",int edad=0,string direccion="",string localidad="",string provincia="",string pais="");
        inline string getCodigo(){return codigo_;}
        inline void setCodigo(string codigo){codigo_=codigo;}
};
```